# How to find migration guide for firebase-functions v4

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

The console informed me yesterday that I should update `firebase-functions` to v4, we've been on v3.21.2. It also informed me that there would be breaking changes.

All I can find it this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v4.0.0, but it'd be great to find a real migration guide? For now I guess I'll search functions wide for the things that are included in that changelog.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firebaser here. There are more detailed release notes [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#cloud-functions-v4-SDK), but no migration guide, sorry! The most important things to do when migrating to `firebase-functions 4.0.0` are:

- [Use Node 14, 16 or 18 (preferably 18)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version)
- Update the `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin`, and `firebase-functions-test` libraries:

  ```
  npm install --save firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest firebase-functions-test@latest
  ```

There are a couple of changes for specific triggers:

- If you're using callable functions & App Check, switch any use of `allowInvalidAppCheckToken` to `enforceAppCheck`
- If you're using Realtime Database triggers, the `DataSnapshot` in the event payload will look a little different, but hopefully in a good way - it will now match the `DataSnapshot` returned by the Admin SDK

Besides that, it's mostly improvements, like better logging, better Typescript types, and new triggers (Remote Config and Test Lab for 2nd-gen functions), as well as a new way to parameterize functions with the [`params` subpackage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/config-env#params). It's always recommended to test functions locally [with the emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator), [`firebase-functions-test`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), or [`functions:shell`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell) to catch errors before deploying to production.